# Question on (im-)possible degree sequences of simple graphs

Tags: graph-theory, solution-verification

We know that I) a sequence of numbers $d_1 \geq \ldots \geq d_n$ is the degree sequence of a (not necessarily simple) graph (there exists a graph with that sequence as degree sequence) iff the sum of the elements in the sequence is even.

Furthermore II) a sequence (like above) is the sequence of a simple graph, iff $d_1 - 1, d_2 -1, \ldots, d_{d_n} - 1, d_{d_n +1}, \ldots, d_n$ is the degree sequence of a simple graph.

Now from that I would conclude that a sequence $d_1 \geq \ldots \geq d_n$ with $d_n = 1$ is never the degree sequence of a simple graph. Since either the sum of $d_1 -1 , d_2, \ldots, d_n$ or the sum of $d_1 , d_2, \ldots, d_n$ is odd and as such with II) one of them is not the degree sequence of a simple graph.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: (I) is Correct , (II) seems **Incorrect** ! Do you have a Source for that Claim ? I think , the last element $d_n$ will be excluded : Both Sums will be Even !

Comment: @Prem It does seem that the second statement is wrong. As far as I can tell the first element should be omitted and then 1 should be subtracted from $d_1$-first elements.
See here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Havel%E2%80%93Hakimi_algorithm

Comment: @Prem your suggestion is also valid!

Comment: While (II) is Incorrect in the Question , there are various ways to make it Correct [[ Eg1 is what I had suggested , to exclude the last element $d_n$ :: Eg2 is to make the last element $2d_n$ :: Eg3 is to append new element $d_n$ at the end :: Eg4 is to make the last element $[d_n \bmod 2]$ :: Eg5 is what you gave :: Eg6 is ETC !! ]]

Comment: Oh yes. That is really interesting, thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, the II) statement does not seem to hold.

In fact the correct formulation of the statement would be that a sequence $d_1, \ldots, d_n$ is the degree sequence of a simple graph iff, $d_2 -1, \ldots, d_{d_1} -1, \ldots, d_n$ is the degre sequence of a simple graph.

Now it is easy to see, that if
$$
2 \mid \sum_{i=1}^n d_i 
$$
Then also
$$
2 \mid \sum_{i=2}^{d_1} d_i -1 + \sum_{i=d_1 +1}^n d_i = \sum_{i=1} ^n d_i - 2 d_i
$$
As such no such statement as I made above can be made about simple graphs.